# c# Decoding string with possible custom logic

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I have the following line in a file

(å\x9C°å\x9D\x803)7SJ686ä¿\x9Dæ\x8A¤è£\Nç½®v1.00.log

And I know this is supposed to represent

(地址3)7SJ686保护装置v1.00.log

But I've not been able to use the right encoding to do so.
I suspect there is some custom logic, example '\N' I believe its being used as a replacement for \x85.

So far, I believe there was some UTF8 decoding and then UTF16 encoding on certain characters (think only for control ones) to obtain the line in the file, but I'm just not being able to solve it properly.

Any ideas?

Hex view of the text and value
[image]
28 C3 A5
5C 78 39 43 C2 B0 C3 A5 5C 78 39 44 5C 78 38 30 33 29 37 53 4A 36 38 36 C3 A4 C2 BF 5C 78 39 44
C3 A6 5C 78 38 41 C2 A4 C3 A8 C2 A3 5C 4E C3 A7 C2 BD C2 AE 76 31 2E 30 30 2E 6C 6F 67

Comment: It'd be helpful to show this string in binary too, to show how this string is represented  exactly in the file.

Comment: Hi @Renat, just updated. Is this ok?

Comment: Looking for patterns... I can see that it ends `v1.00.log` (`76 31 2E 30 30 2E 6C 6F 67`).  And that there's a `3)7SJ686` in the middle (`33 29 37 53 4A 36 38 36`) and a `(` at the start (`28`). You're on your own to fill in the gaps. If I had to guess, it's UTF-8 since it's so ASCII-like for characters `0x20`-`0x7d`

Comment: Go backwards. Take tye string you expect (`(地址3)7SJ686保护装置v1.00.log`), use several encodings (most notably UTF-8) and covers the resulting byte array to hex. Then compare

Comment: Interestingly, this decoder is able to get it right but is obfuscated: https://en.metools.info/enotool/eot121.html

Comment: This one gets it right as UTF8: https://dencode.com/string/hex

Comment: Hi @Flydog57, I noticed that too. I've tried to do a for each encoding GetBytes followed by a for each encoding GetString but I had no success, so I'm not sure what I can try more in terms of encoding.

Comment: @aybe, not sure what you mean on the first link. On the second, I'm not able to transform the first string into the second using any of the options (I tried all of them).

Comment: @FEST What I meant is when you paste the text it produces the hex you both posted, but the opposite is not true in .NET. When you look at comm.js in 1st link, there's an insane amount of code to do the conversion, not a simple call to a well-known library. It seems that they handle some edge cases that .NET implementation doesn't seem to. I tried every single relevant encoding in .NET, none are able to produce the same text. Hope that makes sense now.

Comment: I think the original string is encoded as UTF-**7**, but with unknown characters shown as hex strings in this format `\xFF`.  So for example, `\x9c` represents the Unicode _string terminator_ character (which can also be rendered sometimes as `œ`), `\x9d` is _operating system command_ (no real rendering).  So, what you want to do is read in your string, convert the pattern `\xhh` (where the h's are hex digits) to the byte 0xhh, and then treat it as a UTF-7 string.  I have meetings coming up, but I may try this as an answer in a couple of hours

Answer (score 2):

This is less an answer than it is an overview of some of the investigation I've done.  It's worth noting that, in a previous job, I was the person who ended up trying to figure out why our tools couldn't parse a document submitted by a partner company - I have some homemade tools and quite a bit of experience.

TL;DR: I suspect that you are double-encoding (or, less likely double-decoding) something.

**Starting with your expected string:**

If I take your expected string:
(地址3)7SJ686保护装置v1.00.log

Copy it, and paste into Notepad, and then save it as UTF-8 (with no Byte-Order Mark (or BOM)), I get the following byte stream (determined using PowerShell's `format-hex` command):

```
28 E5 9C B0 E5 9D 80 33 29 37 53 4A 36 38 36 E4
BF 9D E6 8A A4 E8 A3 85 E7 BD AE 76 31 2E 30 30
2E 6C 6F 67
```

Note that it doesn't match what you have shown above.

Now, my main *homemade tool* is a small WinForms app I wrote about a decade ago.  You can open a file, read the contents in as a byte-stream, and then look at what various encodings get rendered as.  If I read that file in, then it's no surprise that the UTF-8 rending looks like:

(地址3)7SJ686保护装置v1.00.log

One of the features of this tool is that if a character is non-printing (a BOM, or a character in the range of 0x00 to 0x20 or 0x7f to 0x9f), it renders the character as a two- or three-character token that represents the name of the Unicode character at that code point (with a distinctive styling).  So, for example, 0x00 is shown as `[NUL]`, 0x0A as `[LF]` and 0x7F as `[DEL]`.  If I look at this style rendering of that string as UTF-7, I see:

(å`[ST]` °å`[ OSC]` `[  PAD]` 3)7SJ686ä¿ `[OSC]` æ `[VTS]` ¤è£ `[NEL]` ç½®v1.00.log

Where

| Mnemonic | Decimal | Hex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ST | 156 | 0x9c |
| OSC | 157 | 0x9d |
| PAD | 128 | 0x80 |
| VTS | 138 | 0x8a |
| NEL | 133 | 0x85 |

Convert those hex values from 0xhh into the form \xHH, and you end up with:

(å`\x9C` °å`\x9D` `\x80` 3)7SJ686ä¿ `\x9D` æ `\x8A` ¤è£ `\x85` ç½®v1.00.log

This compares to what you show in your question:

(å\x9C°å\x9D\x803)7SJ686ä¿\x9Dæ\x8A¤è£\Nç½®v1.00.log

Which to my eye is an exact match.

**Now, going the other way,**

Consider this C# code (the `inputBytes` array are the bytes you show in your question):

```
var inputBytes = new byte[]
{
    0x28, 0xC3, 0xA5, 0x5C, 0x78, 0x39, 0x43, 0xC2,
    0xB0, 0xC3, 0xA5, 0x5C, 0x78, 0x39, 0x44, 0x5C,
    0x78, 0x38, 0x30, 0x33, 0x29, 0x37, 0x53, 0x4A,
    0x36, 0x38, 0x36, 0xC3, 0xA4, 0xC2, 0xBF, 0x5C,
    0x78, 0x39, 0x44, 0xC3, 0xA6, 0x5C, 0x78, 0x38,
    0x41, 0xC2, 0xA4, 0xC3, 0xA8, 0xC2, 0xA3, 0x5C,
    0x4E, 0xC3, 0xA7, 0xC2, 0xBD, 0xC2, 0xAE, 0x76,
    0x31, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x30, 0x2E, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x67
};
var utf8 = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inputBytes);
var utf7 = UTF8Encoding.UTF7.GetString(inputBytes);
```

If I look in the debugger at the `utf8` and `utf7` variables, I see:

- utf8: (å\x9C°å\x9D\x803)7SJ686ä¿\x9Dæ\x8A¤è£\Nç½®v1.00.log
- utf7: (Ã¥\x9CÂ°Ã¥\x9D\x803)7SJ686Ã¤Â¿\x9DÃ¦\x8AÂ¤Ã¨Â£\NÃ§Â½Â®v1.00.log

The `utf7` variable is useless.  However, the `utf8` variable shows the encoded version of the desired string that we decoded using UTF-7.

You don't show enough of what you are doing for me to tell what you did wrong, but I'm pretty sure you went around the merry-go-round one too many times.

If your input really looks like what you say, you are going to need to go through your input byte array looking for 4-byte patterns that look like `\xHH` (like the first one: `5C 78 39 43` - representing `\x9C`) and convert them to single bytes (like 0x9c) and then play with that byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Following analysis of @Flydog57 (thank you so much), I believe I was able to crack it. I'm just worried about the exceptions (ex \N actually means \x85) and I hope there are no others.

```
string final = "(地址3)7SJ686保护装置v1.00.log";
string infile = "(å\\x9C°å\\x9D\\x803)7SJ686ä¿\\x9Dæ\\x8A¤è£\\Nç½®v1.00.log";
var finalBytes = new List<byte>();
for (var i = 0; i < infile.Length; i++)
{
    char c = infile[i];
    if (c == '\\' && i + 3 < infile.Length - 1 && infile[i + 1] == 'x')
    {
        var strByte = infile.Substring(i + 2, 2);
        finalBytes.Add(Convert.ToByte(strByte, 16));
        i += 3;
    }
    else if (c == '\\' && i < infile.Length - 1 && infile[i + 1] == 'N')
    {
        finalBytes.Add(0x85);
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        finalBytes.AddRange(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(new char[] { c }));
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{Convert.ToHexString(finalBytes.ToArray()).Replace("00", "")} -> {c}");
}

var finalHexStr = Convert.ToHexString(finalBytes.ToArray()).Replace("00", "");
var finalStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromHexString(finalHexStr));
Console.WriteLine(final == finalStr);
```

Comment: You more or less ended up doing what I said in my above comment, i.e. the online string converters do some custom logic that .NET doesn't. One thing you could have done is see what libraries that software is using, providing that they are not statically linked and open source, you could look at them to try find the decoding logic in them.